# Is it safe to sign a short token with salted md5

Tags: hash, signature, md5, salt

I want to generate some tokens for client as http cookie

can I md5 them with salt and then use `"<random token>"+"<md5>"` as the token for they
can be verified in a cheap way

is it safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is a message authentication code, or MAC.  In general, you should avoid using Merkle-Dåmgard hash functions (such as MD5, SHA-1, or SHA-2) with a salt or key as a MAC because of length extension attacks, among others.

If you need to generate a MAC of data like this, you should use HMAC with a secure hash function (e.g., SHA-256), KMAC (related to SHA-3), or BLAKE2 with its keyed mode.  If you're not sure what to do, HMAC-SHA-256 is a fine default.

While using MD5 or SHA-1 with HMAC to secure a message doesn't have known practical attacks, there is no good reason to use either MD5 or SHA-1 in a new design, and you should avoid them altogether for any purpose.